# Insert text value in DECIMAL column of table in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, decimal

In text file without commas I have the value of 12345.
The column of `tableA (number1)` is in type `DECIMAL(5,1)`.I want insert the value `12345` in column but first I have to convert it to `1234.5`

How to change it to decimal with and `INSERT` query like below:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (number1) VALUES (...)
```

I tried to use the `CONVERT('12345',DECIMAL(5,1))` function but it becomes like this instead `12345.0`.

Comment: Err, divide it by 10?

Comment: If you specify using your text file into INSERT statement, how about pre-converting your text file and then specifying the values of it in INSERT statement?

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne As you say, it's easier to divide by 10. But I don't know how to generate INSERT statement from the text file. If it is generated by any program, it may be a good way. I may be over thinking...

Comment: @etsuhisa Where in the question does it say anything about 'generating' INSERT statements? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

"12345" will fit in `DECIMAL(5,0)` or `DECIMAL(6,1)` or `DECIMAL(35,30)` but it will overflow `DECIMAL(5,1)`.

The first number is the *total* number of digits.

To treat 12345 as 1234.5, you *must* divide by 10 (or multiply by 0.1)